# Multiple select list not closing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I've been trying to use a select list with `multiple` attribute and `select2 select2-input` class, but as I've shown in the following image, it does not work properly

[image: 1]]

The following is the code I use:

```
 <select id="multilist" class="form-control select2 select2-input" multiple>
                <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="HI" disabled="disabled">Hawaii</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                </optgroup>
 </select>
```

I have also made sure that both JQuery and Bootstrap have been referenced properly.

Update:

The browser's console indicates this causes the problem:

[image]

Comment: Please make this into a working code snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @AJFunk: If this was a working code then I wouldn't need to ask the question :D

Comment: @Arrrr What seems to be issue ? Images dont tell the whole story!

Comment: @DanPhilip: Well, it does seem pretty weird as this always works. I'm using this in an ASP.Net Core MVC app and I can say it only and only fails in there. When using it as an HTML page I don't face the issue. I have checked for conflicts and have removed all other css and js libraries while keeping only those related to JQuery and Bootstrap. The problem doesn't go away though.

Comment: What are the errors being thrown in the console?

Comment: @Arrrr by "working" I mean "reproduces the problem." Showing us how it's broken with a real code snippet allows us to debug it and answer your question.